# Is $f(g,h) = g^2$ a binary operation on a group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

If $(G,\cdot)$ is a group, then $f : G \times G\to G$, defined by $f(g, h) = g^2$, is a binary operation  on $G$. Is it true or false and why?

Comment: Wha's the definition of "binary operation"?

Comment: Why don't you tell us your thoughts on this problem so far. You might also include your book's definition of "binary operation", both to reinforce it in your own mind, and to let us know what assumptions your text is working with. You can do both by clicking on "edit" below your question.

Comment: Have you taken a particular group, say, the integers under addition, and examined $f$ to see whether it has those three properties? (Also: "commutative" seems unlikely to me, but you might be right...)

Comment: $f(g,h)=f(h,g)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(a,f(b,c)) = f(a,b^2) = a^2$

$f(f(a,b),c) = f(a^2, c) = a^4$.

So probably not associative, depending on the $\cdot$ operation.

Comment: @ÀnkitSinghRawat $f(a,b) =a^2$ while $f(b,a) = b^2$ so probably not commutative in most groups.